# Problems with the pip python upgrading

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pip

I'm trying to updating the pip and I get this on the command line.
Also get an upgrade message.

```
Exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 544, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-9.0.1.dist-info\\description.rst' -> 'C:\\Users\\MANUEL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uw3vmwny-uninstall\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-9.0.1.dist-info\\description.rst'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 559, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-9.0.1.dist-info\\description.rst'
```

What I need to do to??
thanks!!

Comment: run `cmd` as admin?

Comment: close any process that opened the file ....\description.rst ?

Comment: What command are you using to update pip?

Answer (score 1):

Just run Command Prompt as Administrator

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28912362)

Comment: @KiranMistry I think ii might provide an answer. but it can use some more pointers on how to execute it. As is, this answer is a bit too concise, Harlienesh. Answers should be short, but complete, and not require any more web searching.

Comment: I think most Windows users will already know how to use this answer as is. I expect this is a useful answer.